# How do i get the positions from Draggable on onDragCompleted?

Tags: flutter, draggable

How can i get the positions on drag complete so that i can move the view to a new position. I'm confused whether dragtarget can achieve this thing

```
  Positioned(
              child: Draggable(
                child: Text(
                  'Simple Text',
                ),
                feedback: Text(
                  'Simple Text',
                ),
                childWhenDragging: Text(
                  'Simple Text',
                ),
              ))
```

Answer (score 3):

Start off with a statefulWidget,
Choose an offset position
Then Override with new position.

```
Offset pos = Offset(50, 50);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
         Positioned(
           top: pos.dy,
           left: pos.dx,
         child: Draggable(
           child: Text(
           'Simple Text',
          ),
         feedback: Text(
           'Simple Text',
          ),
         childWhenDragging: Text(
           'Simple Text',
          ),
         onDraggableCanceled: (view,offset){
           setState(() {
           pos=offset;
         });
         },
         data: ?,
    ),
    ),
```